# Como armar proxy en NodeJS y consumir los assets correctamente

Tags: nodejs, express

Buenas días/tardes/noches a todos; Tengo la siguiente consulta...

Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando un concepto de proxy en nodejs utilizando `http-proxy-middleware`; esto únicamente con fines de prueba y poder ampliar mis conocimientos y quizás a futuro utilizarlo cuando tenga mas proyectos con express...

En fin, armé un sitio simple con express el cual cuenta con su carpeta public; si levanto el proyecto y accedo directamente por el puerto 3001, todo carga perfectamente.

Por lo que cloné dicho proyecto 5 veces, todos con distintos puertos (del 3001 al 3005) para poder probar si funcionaba correctamente ahora al intentar acceder desde `localhost/proy{n}` (dado que el proxy lo puse funcione en los puertos `80` y `443`...

Lo que sería el index del proyecto me cargó en un 80%; Dado que utilizo bootstrap desde CDNJS, pero el resto de los recursos que se encuentran en la carpeta `public` de cada proyecto, no es cargado correctamente; en consola del navegador me retorna este error por ejemplo de uno de los assets que debía cargar `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/css/simple-datatables-bs4.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`, y si se intenta acceder a ese enlace puntual, te carga el index del proxy...

Dado que intente hacer lo mas posible con lo poco que pude comprender con la documentación, preciso ayuda para poder solucionar el inconveniente. Desde ya muchas gracias y adjunto todo el código del proyecto.

```
// Dependencias requeridas
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

try {
    // Contenido certificados
    const sslOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./ssl/cert.key')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./ssl/cert.crt'))
    };

    // Utilidades de seguridad
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.disable('x-powered-by');

    // Endpoints internos
    const endpoints = [
        { webPath: '/proy1',  projectFolder: '/home/web/proy1', port: 3001 },
        { webPath: '/proy2',  projectFolder: '/home/web/proy2', port: 3002 },
        { webPath: '/proy3',  projectFolder: '/home/web/proy3', port: 3003 },
        { webPath: '/proy4',  projectFolder: '/home/web/proy4', port: 3004 },
        { webPath: '/proy5',  projectFolder: '/home/web/proy5', port: 3005 }
    ];

    // Habilitar endpoints en el proxy
    endpoints.forEach(({ webPath, projectFolder, port }) => {
        app.use( webPath, createProxyMiddleware({
            target: `http://localhost:${port}`,
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
                [ `^${webPath}/*` ]: '',
            },
            router: { webPath: (req) => {
                const reformatedPath = req.url.replace(new RegExp(`^${webPath}`), '');
                return `http://localhost:${port}/${reformatedPath}`; }
            }
        }));
        app.use(webPath, express.static(`/home/web/${projectFolder}/public`));
    });

    // Configurar uso de Mustache
    app.set('views', __dirname+'/static');
    app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
    app.engine('mustache', mustacheExpress());

    // Handling toda solicitud que no encaje con proxy
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return res.status(200).render('index', {
            header: " VPS Proxy",
            title: " Bienvenido a mi servidor ",
            message: "Puede que no encuentres mucho, pero es trabajo honesto y del bueno ",
            error_uid: uuidv4()
        });
    });

    // Iniciar servidor HTTPS
    https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(443, () => {
        console.log('[] Proxy iniciado en el puerto 443');
    });

    // Iniciar servidor HTTP
    app.listen(80, () => {
        console.log('[] Proxy iniciado en el puerto 80');
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
}
```